# Objects appear differently depends on devices in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

When I run on iPhone X, objects on a view look being on different position to when run on other devices like iPhone 6.
For example, in this pictures, When I run on iPhone 6s the green and cyan views are on almost same y position as the white triangle of background image. But when run on iPhone X, the two views look on the upper side than the white triangle.

I want to make the objects look on the same position as well as on the other devices when I run on iPhone X.
How can I solve this problem? Do you have any better ideas to adjust layout?

```
class Constants {

    //width of base design size
    static let guiPartsWidthOnDesign = CGFloat(750.0)

    //ratio for layout
    static var guiPartsMultiplier: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / (Constants.guiPartsWidthOnDesign / 2.0)

    //detect safe area
    static let safeArea = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.bottom

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                 height: self.view.frame.size.height)

        //backgrond
        let background = UIImageView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        background.center.x = self.view.frame.size.width/2
        background.image = UIImage(named:"BG")
        background.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        self.view.insertSubview(background, at: 0)

        //downleft blue button
        let blueButton = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(
            x: 64/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
            y: self.view.frame.size.height-(52/2+34/2)*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier-Constants.safeArea!,
            width: 60/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
            height: 52/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier))
        self.view.addSubview(blueButton)
        blueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        //green button
        let greenButton = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(
            x: (60/2+64/2+128/2)*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
            y: self.view.frame.size.height-(52/2+34/2)*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier-Constants.safeArea!,
            width: 60/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
            height: 52/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier))
        self.view.addSubview(greenButton)
        greenButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        //cyan button
        let cyanButton = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(
            x: (64/2+(60/2)*2+(128/2*2))*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
            y: self.view.frame.size.height-(52/2+34/2)*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier-Constants.safeArea!,
            width: 60/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
            height: 52/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier))
        self.view.addSubview(cyanButton)
        cyanButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        //4 blue buttons
        for i in 1..<5 {
            let subBlueButton = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(
                x: 64/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
                y: self.view.frame.size.height-((43.0+CGFloat(50*i))*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier)-Constants.safeArea!,
                width: 60/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
                height: 52/2*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier))
            self.view.addSubview(subBlueButton)
            subBlueButton.alpha = 1.0
            subBlueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }

        //down bar
        let bar = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(
            x:0,
            y: self.view.frame.size.height-50,
            width: self.view.frame.size.width,
            height: 50))
        bar.alpha = 0.3
        bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(bar)

        print("Constants: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, Constants.guiPartsWidthOnDesign, Constants.guiPartsMultiplier)")
        print("SafeArea: \(String(describing: Constants.safeArea))")
        print("Height: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image: iPhone 6s]
[image: iPhone X]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AutoLayout, either in the Storyboard or in code using visual format language.

This tutorial from Ray Wenderlich shows how to use VFL [Ray Wnderlich Visual Format Language](https://www.raywenderlich.com/277-auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial)

[Ray Wederlich Autolayout in Storyboard Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started)

The goal of AutoLayout is to do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The quick workaround would be adding safeAreaLayout using Auto Layout's to Top and Bottom for the background image.

The below code snippet will be useful:

```
 let background = UIImageView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
 background.image = UIImage(named:"bg")
 self.view.insertSubview(background, at: 0)
 background.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
 let statusFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
 NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: background, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: statusFrame).isActive = true
 background.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

 } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
 };
```